# Angular2 - Hot to use custom lib in Angular2

Tags: angular

so i am using this lib called `Janus` it's a javascript for `janus-gateway`, how can i use it in my project?

Tried thus far:

```
  2 var $ = require('jquery');
  3 var Janus = require('../../vendor/janus');
```

Janus is jquery dependant. Jquery seems to work, but not `Janus`.
pastebin for janus.js: http://pastebin.com/MdUxTbDU

I am using Angular2 with typescript.

Error produced:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Janus.init is not a function TypeError: Janus.init is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:372:20)
    at mightThrow (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:47178:30)
    at process (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:47246:13)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14544:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14444:48)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14612:34) undefined
zone.js:140 Uncaught TypeError: Janus.init is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the JavaScript file(s) for your library in your index.html file and inside your angular 2 component declare it using the following statement at the top.

`declare var Janus: any;`

Then start using `Janus.[anything]` in your component.

You can use any third party library like this.

Comment: But wouldn't it impact performance? Like webpack thing and such?

Comment: as far as you're not including hundreds of libraries in your index file and you use the minified versions of your libraries, it shouldn't impact performance. If you do need to use several libraries this way, I would advise you to combine them together in a single file and then run a minifier on it and then include that single minified js file in your index file.

Comment: Also, i need to use jquery in my controller and in janus(Janus loads jquery too). How would one make sure it doesnt load jquey twice?

Comment: Well, that's a different debate. But you can load jQuery first and after that Janus. As good programming practices say, you should always do null, undefined, exists checks before using a library in your project. So Janus should have those conditions in it's library. I wouldn't advise you to do modifications in the library if there isn't, but if that's a show stopper for you, you can always do it.